# Is it possible to find the orthogonal complement of a single vector (something that is not a subspace)?

Tags: orthogonality

This is the problem that I have been asked:

Find the orthogonal complement of the transpose of the vector = [3,4,1]. Also find the point on the plane 2x-3y+z=0 which is closest to (3,4,1).

I know how to do the second part of the this problem, and I don't have any issues with it. The first sentence doesn't quite make sense to me though. I don't know how to find the orthogonal complement of a single vector that is not a subspace. I have tried looking this up online, but every place that I check, it always prefaces the explanation by saying that this is how you find the orthogonal complement to some subspace. Am I wrong in thinking that it does not make sense to ask about the orthogonal complement of a non-subspace?

Comment: can we use calculus?

Comment: I don't know that it would necessarily be something that I could use for this assignment, but I would definitely like to learn about how to use it.

Comment: The orthogonal compliment of a vector is the subspace spanned by all vectors orthogonal to it. This is identical to the orthogonal compliment of the subspace spanned by that vector. The orthogonal compliment of a one dimensional subspace like this is called a hyperplane so they're important enough to get their own name.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - You don't need the span. The orthogonal complement of a vector is the _set_ of all vectors orthogonal to it. This is in fact a subspace.

Comment: @mr_e_man I know. That's the first sentence I wrote in my comment.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - No, you referred to the span of all orthogonal vectors. You could have referred to the set of all orthogonal vectors. Of course they're the same; my point is that you're doing extra work, taking the (linear) closure of something that's already closed.

Comment: @mr_e_man You seem to already know that we're talking about exactly the same set of vectors so it's unclear to me where your confusion lies. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @CyclotomicField - I'm not the OP.

Comment: @mr_e_man I'm talking to you because you made these comments. I really don't understand what you're talking about and I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: @mr_e_man ok I think I figured it out. I used the word span twice to reinforce the fact that the orthogonal compliment of the vector was the orthogonal compliment of its spanning set since that's where they were making the mistake. It's just boring old repetition to encourage retention.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - I'm not confused. When you mentioned my confusion, it seemed that you thought I had asked a question, which only the OP did.

Comment: There are two spans which don't need to be taken: $$\{v\}^\perp=(\text{span}\{v\})^\perp$$ $$=\{w\mid v\cdot w=0\}=\text{span}\{w\mid v\cdot w=0\}$$ I was mainly pointing out the last equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution based on calculus uses partial differentiation.

First we construct a function called "distance from position $(3,4,1)$"

This is
$d=\sqrt{x-3)^2+(y-4)^2+(z-1)^2}$
which gives the distance from  generic point $(x,y,z)$ just to $(3,4,1)$.

Now we take the auxiliar function
$$F=2x-3y+z+\lambda d^2,$$
The we seek the minimum of $F$ which will be attained a critical point, that is, at  a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ which solves
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0.$$
So we get
$$2+\lambda 2(x-3)=0,$$
$$-3+\lambda 2(y-4)=0,$$
$$1+\lambda 2(z-1)=0,$$
which can be arranged as
$$\lambda=\dfrac{1}{3-x}=\dfrac{3}{2(y-4)}=\dfrac{1}{2(1-z)},$$
these, together with the restriction
$$2x-3y+z+0,$$
would imply
$$x_0=\frac{26}{7}\,\ y_0=\dfrac{41}{14} \ ,\ z_0=\dfrac{19}{14}.$$

Comment: This would sound to you automatic but consider it as a foothold, a fulcrum.